# PHP-Insert Query Result into another Query Statement

Tags: javascript, php, cordova

I want to run these 3 queries together.
How do I fetch the Case_ID from the 2nd query to insert into the 3rd query's Case_ID ?

```
$query = "insert into `Case`(`informant_userid`,`CaseName`,`CaseTime`) values ('" . $informant_userid . "','" . $CaseName . "',now())";
$query = "SELECT `Case_ID` from `Case` ORDER BY `Case_ID` DESC LIMIT 1 ";
$query = "insert into Picture (Case_Pic,Case_ID) values ('" .addslashes($imagefile). "','" .$Case_ID"')" ;
```

Comment: Have you tried  _insert into Picture (Case_Pic,Case_ID) values ('" .addslashes($imagefile). "', (SELECT `Case_ID` from `Case` ORDER BY `Case_ID` DESC LIMIT 1))_ ?

Comment: @DIe just tried it, the Case_ID equals 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `CaseID` is an auto-increment column. Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the value that was assigned in the most recent `INSERT`.

```
$query = "insert into `Case`(`informant_userid`,`CaseName`,`CaseTime`) values ('" . $informant_userid . "','" . $CaseName . "',now())";
// execute $query
$query = "insert into Picture (Case_Pic,Case_ID) values ('" .addslashes($imagefile). "', LAST_INSERT_ID())" ;
// execute $query
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, you're right about the auto-increment `CaseID`. However, I tried your codes but `CaseID` result is still 0.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same database connection for both queries. `LAST_INSERT_ID()` is per-connection.

Comment: I am using the same database connection for both queries `$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "-", "-", "-");`

Comment: If you're using mysqli, why are you using `addslashes` instead of `$conn->real_escape_string`? Better yet, use prepared queries and `bind_param()`.

Comment: I don't know why `LAST_INSERT_ID()` isn't working for you. Are you sure the `INSERT` is successful?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a stored procedure to run this queries together.

Example:

```
BEGIN
  insert into `Case`(`informant_userid`,`CaseName`,`CaseTime`) values ('" . $informant_userid . "','" . $CaseName . "',now());

  SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

You can use `out_param` value as a case number else also you can run select query and assign values to variable as below.

```
SELECT @param1 = col1,  @param2 = col2, ...
FROM TABLE1
WHERE <where_clause>
```

You can see more details from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx)

Comment: Hi Tiger, after I run `SET out_param = LAST_INSERT_ID();` , how do I execute the 3rd query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [INSERT INTO SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) statement with a little trick. This statement inserts the result of the SELECT query into the target table(Picture).

```
"INSERT INTO Picture (Case_Pic,Case_ID) 
SELECT '" . addslashes($imagefile) . "' AS Case_Pic, Case_ID FROM `Case` 
ORDER BY Case_ID DESC LIMIT 1"
```

To include the Case_Pic in the result the column alias is used.